# How to send request_uri as query parameter in proxy_pass in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have below nginx configuration

```
server {
listen 80;
client_max_body_size 10M;
keepalive_timeout    15;
server_name mysite.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://anothersite.com
}
}
```

Above is working, but I need something like below:

location / {
       proxy_pass http://anothersite.com?q=request_uri so I can pass request_uri as a query parameter.

Can you please provide correct syntax for passing request_uri as query parameter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `rewrite` your `request_uri` using regular expressions.

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.+)$ ?q=$1
    proxy_pass http://anothersite.com;
}
```

The `rewrite` rule matches any `request_uri` starting with `/` and captures any non-empty string which comes afterwards (.+). It then rewrites the `request_uri` to `?q=` followed by whatever came after the `/`. Since your `proxy_pass` directive doesn't end with an `/` it will append the rewritten `request_uri` to the proxy target.

So a request to `http://yoursite.com/some/api` would be rewritten and proxy-passed to `http://anothersite.com?q=some/api`

Hope that is what you want!